# Function mysql in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, cakephp

I'm trind to do a query like this:

```
$this->set('title', 'Lista de Posts');
$Posts = $this->Post->query("SELECT id,Titulo,Data,Hora,RIGHT(Conteudo,200) AS Conteudo,Usuario FROM posts;");
$this->set('posts', $Posts);
$this->layout = 'home';
```

But in the view i receive this message:

Notice (8): Undefined index: Post [APP/View/Posts/home.ctp, line 4]

But with $Posts = $this->Post->find('all') it works.

Please can anyone help me to use RIGHT(Conteudo,200) in cake php?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget the 'query' method if you're new with Cake. It is for very special cases.

In your PostsController:

```
class PostsController extends AppController {

    var $helpers = array('Text');

    public function index() {
        $posts = $this->paginate();
        $this->set('posts', $posts);
    }
}
```

In your view:

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
  echo $this->Text->tail($post['Post']['conteudo'], 200);
}
```

Comment: I put the helper :
var $helpers = array('String','Html','Form', 'Session');

But returned this error : Error: StringHelper could not be found.

Comment: try a 'Text' instead of 'String'

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure what's causing the notice in your view because you haven't posted enough code.

Are you trying to do this? `echo $posts['Post']['Conteudo']`

Given your query, RIGHT(Conteudo,200) will be at `$posts[0]['Conteudo']` since Cake doesn't know what table the virtual function derives from.

Check out [the CakePHP documentation on virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) for information on using SQL functions and virtual fields.

Here's a short (untested) code snippet that may help:

```
$this->virtualFields = array( 'ConteudoRight' => 'RIGHT(Conteudo,200)' );

$Posts = $this->Post->find('all', array(
   'fields' => array( 'id', 'RIGHT(Conteudo,200) AS Post__ConteudoRight' )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pr($Posts) in controller just to test the results. It will let you know the difference in results you are getting in 2 cases.